# shopware 6 article number with random string in url

Tags: shopware

In Shopware 6 I have this product url:

```
/{{ product.autoIncrement }}/{{ product.translated.name|lower}}/
```

As example: `/1539/mercedes-benz/`

Is it possible to make the productname free text? So if I enter the url `/1539/mercedesbenzzz/` that I go to the same product?

I have tried to override `SeoUrlPlaceholderHandlerInterface` but I think this is not the right way. Any idea?

Comment: I posted an answer and deleted it because I misunderstood your question. As I understand it now, you want the user to be able to access the page, regardless what they enter after the `autoIncrement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwriting `SeoUrlPlaceholderHandlerInterface` would not help, because this is for generating the URLs which are stored in the Shopware 6 database.

What you want is to overwriting the routing, so Shopware only matches by the auto increment Id.

Use the debug bar to find out which router is used for the product pages and modify it.

Starting points:

- `\Shopware\Storefront\Framework\Routing\RequestTransformer::resolveSeoUrl`
- `\Shopware\Core\Content\Seo\SeoResolver::resolve`